# Raspberry pi 3: is not ready to pair -BLUETOOTH

Tags: bluetooth

I need to connect my android phone to my pi3 via bluetooth and with a PIN.
I am using blueZ4.0.1 https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/test/simple-agent
this is what I did:
on my terminal, I wrote this to make the phone ask for a PIN:

`hciconf hci0 sspmode 0`

then this is my script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib
try:
from gi.repository import GObject
except ImportError:
import gobject as GObject
import bluezutils #this is from root/bluez/bluezutils https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/bluezutils.py


BUS_NAME = 'org.bluez'
AGENT_INTERFACE = 'org.bluez.Agent1'
AGENT_PATH = "/test/autoagent"
bus = None
device_obj = None
dev_path = None


def ask(prompt):
   try:
      return raw_input(prompt)
   except:
      return input(prompt)


def set_trusted(path):
    props = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", path),
"org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
    props.Set("org.bluez.Device1", "Trusted", True)
def dev_connect(path):
    dev = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", path),
"org.bluez.Device1")
    dev.Connect()



class Rejected(dbus.DBusException):
    _dbus_error_name = "org.bluez.Error.Rejected"



class Agent(dbus.service.Object):
  exit_on_release = True
  def set_exit_on_release(self, exit_on_release):
      self.exit_on_release = exit_on_release
      @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
     in_signature="", out_signature="")


  def Release(self):
      print("Release")
      if self.exit_on_release:
            mainloop.quit()
       @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
       in_signature="os", out_signature="")


   def AuthorizeService(self, device, uuid):
      print("AuthorizingService (%s, %s)" % (device, uuid))
      return
     @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
       in_signature="o", out_signature="s")


   def RequestPinCode(self, device):
        print("RequestPinCode (%s)" % (device))
        set_trusted(device)
        return "1111"
        @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
      in_signature="o", out_signature="u")


   def RequestPasskey(self, device):
        print("RequestPasskey (%s)" % (device))
        set_trusted(device)
      return dbus.UInt32(0000) #hard code PIN to 0000
      @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
     in_signature="ouq", out_signature="")


   def DisplayPasskey(self, device, passkey, entered):
      print("DisplayPasskey (%s, %06u entered %u)" %
                        (device, passkey, entered))
     @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
    in_signature="os", out_signature="")


   def DisplayPinCode(self, device, pincode):
     print("DisplayPinCode (%s, %s)" % (device, pincode))
    @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
     in_signature="ou", out_signature="")


   def RequestConfirmation(self, device, passkey):
    print("RequestConfirmation (%s, %06d)" % (device, passkey))
        confirm = ask("Confirm passkey (yes/no): ")
    return
     @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
      in_signature="o", out_signature="")


   def RequestAuthorization(self, device):
     print("RequestAuthorization (%s)" % (device))
     return
   @dbus.service.method(AGENT_INTERFACE,
     in_signature="", out_signature="")


   def Cancel(self):
    print("Cancel")

def pair_reply():
    print("Device paired")
    set_trusted(dev_path)
    dev_connect(dev_path)


def pair_error(error):
    err_name = error.get_dbus_name()
    if err_name == "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply" and device_obj:
          print("Timed out. Cancelling pairing")
          device_obj.CancelPairing()
    else:
          print("Creating device failed: %s" % (error))





if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    capability = "NoInputNoOutput"
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--adapter", action="store",type="string", dest="adapter_pattern", default=None)
    parser.add_option("-c", "--capability", action="store", type="string", dest="capability")
    parser.add_option("-t", "--timeout", action="store",type="int", dest="timeout",default=60000)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()


     if options.capability:
        capability  = options.capability
    path = "/test/autoagent"
    agent = Agent(bus, path)
    mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()
    obj = bus.get_object(BUS_NAME, "/org/bluez");
    manager = dbus.Interface(obj, "org.bluez.AgentManager1")
    manager.RegisterAgent(path, capability)
    print("Agent registered")

    # Fix-up old style invocation (BlueZ 4)


    if len(args) > 0 and args[0].startswith("hci"):
        options.adapter_pattern = args[0]
        del args[:1]


    if len(args) > 0:
        device = bluezutils.find_device(args[0],
                        options.adapter_pattern)
        dev_path = device.object_path
        agent.set_exit_on_release(False)
        device.Pair(reply_handler=pair_reply, error_handler=pair_error, timeout=60000)
        device_obj = device
    else:
        manager.RequestDefaultAgent(path)
    mainloop.run()
```

and I successfully was able to send a PIN from my android phone, however, the 2 devices are not getting paired because my android phone is telling me "unable to connect with pi. make sure your pi is ready to pair".

It is not checking if the PIN on both sides are compatible and pairing them. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you expect that we follow all the tutorials and programs to understand what the problem is? I suggest to debug your code.

Comment: i hope now it is more clear